Visual Studio. No se puede cargar el servicio de confianza
No se que ha pasado pero no cualquier proyecto que intento abrir con Visual Studio (Community 2022 - 17.11.4) ahora me dice: "No se puede cargar el servicio de confianza. Las comprobaciones de confianza están deshabilitadas en este momento."
Lo primero que he hecho es reparar y actualizar visual studio y no se ha arreglado
Lo segundo que he hecho es tratar de ir a  Herramientas > Opciones > Entorno > Configuración de confianza y resulta que no hay nada.
Cuando creo algun proyecto nuevo como una aplicación de consola, me aparece esto

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de que puedo hacer?
¿Quizás borrar la caché? ¿Alguien sabe como se hace?
Muchas gracias

Para borrar el caché de visual studio dirigete e la ruta ve a %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio

y elimina las carpetas que inicien con la versión que estés utilizando. Ej. 17.0_

Si tienes extensiones instaladas, valida que no te esté alguna causando ese problema.

Que va, si he desinstalado el visual y las sdks, lo he vuelto a instalar y sigue sin funcionar... Sospecho que es que descargué algo llamado Hosting Bundle en la misma maquina en lugar de en una maquina virtual y aunque ahora lo he desinstalado, sospecho que se habrá quedado algun fichero tonto por ahí... me tocará formatear la maquina  :'(

me ha ocurrido lo mismo, lo he podido solucionar renombrado el fichero DefinitionCache.sqlite en la ruta
C:\Users<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_00df5de5\UnifiedSettings

Que grande, yo reseteé el ordenador :')
